# How to synchronize database in mysql command line client

Tags: sql, database, synchronization, mysql

I've read some answers about syncronizing `MySQL` database, but all I saw is about syncronizing database in model schema. Maybe I am wrong but I think there must be a way to perform that action.

> Now currently I inserted lot of records in **`MySQL command line client`** , as a reason of freezing MySQL Workbench in Windows, but I need to sync those records to **`model schema`** of the database.

The figure below illustrates that I've inserted the records.
[image]

---

And the figure below illustrates that I want to syncronize the records.
[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question... if you insert a record from command line it will be avilable from Workbench too. Can you explain with sample data?

Comment: Of course, it is also available inserting records in Workbench, but it always freezes while inserting. So, I've prepared sql commands to insert records in command line, and all the records are inserted to the specific table. I also need the database model have the records, but there is no any data as you see in the second figure.

Comment: You can refresh as you want... or do you need automatic refresh in workbench?

Comment: Automatic refresh would be perfect, but currently there will not any change, neither I refresh it nor I don't.

Comment: It can't be possible, because Workbenck don't have a "live view" of data... may be you need some development to view live data.